# Prob. 6, Sec. 3.4 in Kreyszig's functional analysis book: The fourier coefficients minimise the distance.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, inner-products

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\{ e_1, \ldots, e_n \}$ be an orthonormal set in an inner product space $X$, let $x \in X$, let $y(x) \colon= \sum_{j=1}^n \langle x, e_j \rangle e_j$, and let $z \colon= \sum_{j=1}^n \gamma_j e_j$, where $\gamma_1, \ldots, \gamma_n$ are any scalars. Then how to show that 
$$\Vert x-y(x) \Vert \leq \Vert x-z \Vert,$$
where $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is the norm induced by the inner product $\langle \cdot \rangle$?

My effort:

\begin{align}
\Vert x-z \Vert^2 - \Vert x-y(x) \Vert^2 
&= \langle x-z, \ x-z \rangle - \langle x-y(x), \ x-y(x) \rangle \\
&= - 2 \Re \langle x, z \rangle + \Vert z \Vert^2 +  2 \Re \langle x, y(x) \rangle - \Vert y(x) \Vert^2 \\
&= - 2 \Re \sum_{j=1}^n \langle x, e_j \rangle \overline{\gamma_j} + \sum_{j=1}^n \vert \gamma_j \vert^2  +  2 \sum_{j=1}^n \vert \langle x, e_j \rangle \vert^2 - \sum_{j=1}^n \vert \langle x, e_j \rangle \vert^2 \\
&= - 2 \Re \sum_{j=1}^n \langle x, e_j \rangle \overline{\gamma_j} + \sum_{j=1}^n \vert \gamma_j \vert^2  +   \sum_{j=1}^n \vert \langle x, e_j \rangle \vert^2 \\
&\geq - 2 \left\vert \sum_{j=1}^n \langle x, e_j \rangle \overline{\gamma_j} \right\vert + \sum_{j=1}^n \vert \gamma_j \vert^2  +   \sum_{j=1}^n \vert \langle x, e_j \rangle \vert^2 \\
&\geq - 2 \sum_{j=1}^n \left\vert  \langle x, e_j \rangle \overline{\gamma_j} \right\vert + \sum_{j=1}^n \vert \gamma_j \vert^2  +   \sum_{j=1}^n \vert \langle x, e_j \rangle \vert^2 \\
&\geq - 2 \sqrt{ \sum_{j=1}^n \left\vert  \langle x, e_j \rangle \right\vert^2} \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n \left\vert \overline{\gamma_j} \right\vert^2} + \sum_{j=1}^n \vert \gamma_j \vert^2  +   \sum_{j=1}^n \vert \langle x, e_j \rangle \vert^2 \\
&=  - 2 \sqrt{ \sum_{j=1}^n \left\vert  \langle x, e_j \rangle \right\vert^2} \cdot \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n \left\vert \gamma_j \right\vert^2} + \sum_{j=1}^n \vert \gamma_j \vert^2  +   \sum_{j=1}^n \vert \langle x, e_j \rangle \vert^2 \\
&= \left(\sqrt{ \sum_{j=1}^n \left\vert  \langle x, e_j \rangle \right\vert^2} -  \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n \left\vert \gamma_j \right\vert^2}  \right)^2 \\
&\geq 0.
\end{align}

Is this calculation correct? If not, then where does the problem lie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that
$$
       \left(x-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k\right) \perp e_j,\;\;\; j=1,2,3,\cdots, n.
$$
Therefore, for all scalars $\beta_1,\beta_2,\cdots,\beta_n$,
$$
                   \left(x-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle x,e_k\rangle e_k\right)\perp\sum_{j=1}^{n}\beta_j e_j
$$
Therefore, by the Pythagorean Theorem,
\begin{align}
    \left\|x-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_je_j\right\|^2&=
    \left\|\left(x-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\langle x,e_j\rangle e_j\right)+\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\langle x,e_j\rangle-\alpha_j)e_j\right\|^2 \\
   & = \left\|x-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\langle x,e_j\rangle e_j\right\|^2+\left\|\sum_{j=1}^{n}(\langle x,e_j\rangle-\alpha_j)e_j\right\|^2
\end{align}
Now you can see that the following holds for all choices of $\alpha_j$
$$
   \left\|x-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\alpha_je_j\right\| \ge \left\|x-\sum_{j=1}^{n}\langle x,e_j\rangle e_j\right\|,
$$
and you have equality iff $\alpha_j = \langle x,e_j\rangle$ for all $j$.

Comment: your answer is just beautiful! Can you please also have a look at my solution and see if there're any problems?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud : Your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation looks good. There is, however, an easier solution. First, it is not hard to prove that the law of cosines also holds in arbitrary Hilbert spaces:
$$\|x-z\|^2 = \|x - y\|^2 + \| z - y\|^2 - 2 \, \Re \langle z - y , x - y\rangle$$
for all $x,y,z$ in a Hilbert space. This relation is also convenient to use in other situations.

In your situation, you have $\langle z - y(x), x - y(x)\rangle = 0$ due to the construction of $y(x)$. Hence,
$$\|x - z\|^2 = \|x - y(x)\|^2 + \|z - y(x)\|^2 \ge \|x - y(x)\|^2.$$
This method has the advantage that you can precisely characterize the difference of the (squared) norms, since
$$\|z - y(x)\|^2 = \sum_{j = 1}^n |\gamma_j - \langle x,e_j\rangle|^2.$$

(by the way: this can also be seen from your fourth line, so you can short-cut your proof.)